# Storage options would give the organization the best chance of recovering data

Tags: encryption, storage, data-recovery

I am studying information security, I have a question that I need help with.

> Which of the following storage options would give the organization the
> best chance of recovering data?
>
> A. Encrypted physical copies of the data and their encryption keys are
> stored together at the organization and are readily available upon
> request
>
> B. Encrypted physical copies of the data are stored separately from
> their encryption keys and both are held in secure locations a few
> hours away from the organization.
>
> C. Encrypted reports on usage and database structure changes are
> stored on a cloud-based. secured database that is readily accessible.
>
> D. Encrypted copies of the data are stored in a separate secure
> location a few hours away while the encryption keys are stored at the
> organization and are readily available.

I think B is correct. But I am told that D is the best method because there is a chance we lost the encryption key at the organization if the company faces disaster (bomb, explosion, fire...). Can anyone tell me and explain why?

Comment: I love these. There's a chance that the key storage location will experience disaster, too ... There must be more to the context.

Comment: I think B is correct, but I am not an expert on this so I am not sure. Physical copies of data and relevant encryption keys are separate from each other, and far from the production site of the organization. And, we reduce the chance that encryption face incidents too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, A and C are right out. So it comes down to weighing the benefits of B and D.

This is one of those questions that are supposed to "get you thinking", but I think it tries to be too clever. It becomes a philosophical discussion.

With B, you are protected from events ***happening at the company location***. But you increase your hazard surface. Now there are 2 places that need to remain intact; the data location and the key location. And you potentially lose control over the keys (but that can be an assumption).

With D, you have only 1 crucial location (the data location), and a smaller hazard area than B. But any disaster in the company location means that recovery is impossible.

So, it becomes a risk calculation based on requirements and what you *actually* want to protect against. I suspect there might be more context to the question that you have not provided. But on the other hand, I've seen these "too clever" questions quite a lot.

Comment: Context: That is a question from my file which I am studying. But the keyword about the questions is "best chance of recovering data". So, based on that, please help.
Anyway, thank bout your thought about "too clever" questions.

Comment: No, by context, I mean the context of the scenario. And you have my help.

Comment: I just edit my comment. But the keyword about the questions is "best chance of recovering data". So, based on that, please help. Anyway, thank bout your thought about "too clever" questions. I am new to StackExchange so I think enter make new line, but it post immediately.

Comment: If someone presented this question to *me*, I'd ask the age-old security question: best chance against *what* threat?